# Trace map $\gamma:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$ invertible on $\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \Delta u =0 \}.$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

It is apparently true that the trace map $\gamma:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$, is invertible when restricted to the domain
$$\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \Delta u =0 \}.$$

I've been wondering why all morning but I've had no luck. OK, one can set up the well-posed problem $$\Delta u = 0$$ $$\gamma(u) = v$$
but I see no reason why I cannot have a $\Delta u = f \in H^{-1}$ instead.

Comment: Not sure myself, but could it be to do with $f$ being only $H^{-1}$ (and so not very regular) destroying some boundary regularity?

Comment: What are the assumptions on the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: @Behaviour I had in mind $\Omega = M \times (0,\infty)$ where $M$ is a closed $C^2$ manifold. But let us take it to be a plain smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @BaronMingus I am thinking that: the trace map is invertible if $\gamma(u_1) = \gamma(u_2)$ implies $u_1 = u_2$. When $u_1$ and $u_2$ are harmonic, the difference solves $\Delta d = 0$ and $\gamma(d) = 0$. Then doesn't this imply $d=0$ since problem is well-posed? In this case, the region of invertiblity makes sense as $\{ u \in H^1(\Omega) \mid \Delta u = f\}$ for a fixed $f$. ??

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a bounded domain then, there is only one "harmonic" function $u$, which satisfies $\gamma(u)=v$ for fixed $v\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$.